# need to select core data in restkit configured App and post it

Tags: core-data, post, boolean, restkit, predicate

I haven't been able to find examples of selecting data from an existing Core Data SQLite DB and POSTing it. My Core Data seems configured ok according to the debug output. I have set it display SQLite operations. When I try to do either a predicate on a Boolean attribute or a load all it doesn't give be an error but it retrieves zero objects.

```
@interface Offering : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * uploadToServerRequired; 



#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "Offering.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions


    RKObjectManager* manager = 
    [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL: [[NSURL  alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/anywhereAboutWebServices"] ];
    manager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"AnywhereAbout2.sqlite"];

 NSError *error;

    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AnywhereAbout2.sqlite"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil] error:&error]);
    else {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: persistentStoreCoordinator];

    }

    NSArray* objects = [Offering allObjects];
    NSLog(@"We loaded %d objects", [objects count]);

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uploadToServerRequired == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool: (BOOL)1]];


    int count = [filtered count];
```

Comment: why am I not getting any results (why is this not working) and side question : has anyone seen a good example of posting from core data. I bought a book on core data and I think I almost have the answer to the main question: needs some more linkage to managed object context.

Comment: You are native mixing core data code with Restkit and this leads me to think you are not doing things "normally". Download RestKit and look at their RKTwitterCoreData example.

Comment: added following and got it to work

Comment: NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Offering" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    
    NSError *anyError = nil;
    NSArray *fetched = [__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error: &anyError];
    if (fetched == nil) {
         NSLog(@"Error with fetch");
    }
    NSLog(@"We fetched %d objects", [fetched count]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added following and got it to work:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Offering" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSError *anyError = nil;
NSArray *fetched = [__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error: &anyError];
if (fetched == nil) {
     NSLog(@"Error with fetch");
}
NSLog(@"We fetched %d objects", [fetched count]);
```